# How to provide relative path in Include controller in jmeter for test fragment

Tags: jmeter, controller, web-api-testing

I have two thread groups from that in one thread I have two include controllers. but I want to provide relative path instead of absolute path so anyone can use this project in their system. as I am uploading this on GitHub.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRip1.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. If the external .jmx script lives at the same folder - just use its filename like `Test Fragment.jmx` in the Include Controller

   If it resides under a folder - specify its relative location

   ```
   somefolder/Test Fragment.jmx
   ```

   For the parent folder:

   ```
   ../somefolder/Test Fragment.jmx
   ```
2. There is [`includecontroller.prefix` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#include_controller) which is being added to the filename specified so if there is a common location for all external JMX files/test fragments you might want to set this property

More information:

- [Include Controller Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)
- [Modularizing for Script Reusability: Examples in JMeter and YAML](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/modularizing-for-script-reusability-examples-in-jmeter-and-yaml)

Comment: Thanks. its working as .jmx script is in the same folder.